# Consultas de registros en tablas muchos a muchos con laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Como haria al momento de consultar los registros de dos tablas relacionadas (muchos a muchos) mediante una tabla pivote de laravel?

Trato de hacerlo con Joins, pero no logro dar con lo que quiero. Las tablas son:

```
user
role_user
roles
```

Comment: ¿qué es lo que quieres obtener exactamente?

Comment: Obtener el registro de un usuario con su rol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que las relaciones estén bien definidas en los modelos, solo tienes que hacer:

```
$user->role;
```

En la documentación se explica detalladamente esto: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Lo ideal sería que tus tablas se llamaran `users` (con s al final), `roles` y `role_user`, la cual debe contener `user_id` y `role_id`.

De ahí en adelante configurar los modelos es muy sencillo:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Role:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

**Edición:**

Un ejemplo rápido para mostrar los usuarios con sus roles:

Controlador

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();

    return view('users.list', compact('users'));
}
```

Vista

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    Usuario: {{ $user->name }} Rol: {{ $user->role->role_name }}
@endofeach
```

Obviamente los nombres de las propiedades cambian. Te recomiendo que leas como funcionan las relaciones en Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Tengo los modelos tal cual los muestras y van al pelo. Solo me confunde un poco al momento de traer los registros.

Hago el llamdo $users = User::find(1)->roles()->orderBy('id')->get();

Pero solo me retorna el name del rol y necesito que tambien me retorne el registro del usuario...

Comment: No entiendo para que quieres hacer eso, estás haciendo un query a la relación totalmente innecesario, si te fijas al inicio de la respuesta dice `$user->role`, eso es todo lo que necesitas, creo que no has entendido bien como funcionan las relaciones en Laravel, para lo cual te sugiero que leas bien su documentación, pues ya están precargadas.

Comment: Fino, pero cuando hago el llamado ( $user->role; ) desde el controlador, me genera el error de variable indefinida.

Comment: ¿Estás definiendo `$user` antes? De ser afirmativo, entonces probablemente está mal definida la relación, ¿revisaste que los nombres de las tablas y de los campos coincidan? eso es muy importante y normalmente las personas se equivocan ahí al olvidar o poner una s de más.

Comment: A ver, este el fragmento del controlador donde hago el llamado.

public function index()
    {
        $roles = Role::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();

        //$users = User::find(1)->roles()->orderBy('id')->get();

        $user->role;

        //dd($users);
        return view('users.users', compact('roles', 'user'));
    }

Comment: No se si me falta algo. Las relaciones las he probado con tinker y van bien. Hago la insercción desde la vista y van bien...

Comment: No sé que es lo que pretendes hacer, pero creo que no has entendido el concepto de las relaciones en Laravel, ¿asumo que estás imprimiendo un listado de usuarios?

Comment: Exactamente es lo que quiero. Imprimir el registro de los usuarios con sus respectivos roles.

Comment: Ver edición de la respuesta.

Comment: Solucionado amigo.!... Un simple detalle que estaba obviando, puesto que modelos y relaciones, estan perfectas. Gracias!!!